# Handling HTTP Requests with C in Nginx

Tags: c, http, nginx, request

How can I process a request with C in Nginx?

It would be great if you provide some sort of example, source code or documentation and configuration needed for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to serve compiled binary files with nginx, you need to run another server called FCGI, telling it the path to each binary you wish to serve, then configuring nginx to proxy connections to that server.

Example configuration:

```
http
{
  server
  {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /
    {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8000;

      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

You tell FCGI which binaries you wish to serve like so:

```
spawnfcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 -f /path/to/binary
```

Once requests are successfully redirected to the binary, a simple hello world may be written like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf ("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
  printf ("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
  return 0;
}
```

To handle GET and POST data respectively, you must parse them from the environment variable `QUERY_STRING` and standard input, respectively. The length of the POST data is given by the `CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable. Example:

```
printf ("My GET data is: %s<br>", getenv ("QUERY_STRING"));

int len = atoi (getenv (CONTENT_LENGTH));
char *buf = malloc (len + 1);
read (0, buf, len);
buf[len] = 0;

printf ("My POST data is: %s<br>", buf);
```

In my opinion, nginx is not the optimal choice for serving CGI. Take a look at [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).